# how to change background color of row based on page item value in interactive report

Tags: javascript, oracle, report, oracle-apex, apex

[image: this is my report screen]

hello guys, i have a question,
in my program,
there is a hidden page item, when i click any row of the order report,
hidden page item takes the order id,
than i change the order details table with the page item value.

everything is okay for now, i have order id on page item, with this value i want to change the background color of the that row

i mean for example page item hold 2 and if it holds 2, i want to change the background color of the row on the order table where order id is 2.

i hope, I hope I explained to you correctly

Comment: You should include an example of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with a CSS rule:

```
tr.highlighted {
  background: orange;
}
```

Then you just need to select your hidden page item

```
document.querySelector("table tr:nth-of-type([item#])").addClass("highlighted");
```